# PlaceHolder in JSF with DatePicker?

Tags: jquery, html, jsf, jsf-2, datepicker

I'm trying to find a solution for `<input placeholder="text inside input field">` from `HTML5` to `JSF`. So I found out about two solutions, one for [primefaces](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/watermark.jsf;jsessionid=1hjjdtstqf6681oz9i102dul45) and another for [richfaces](http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=inplaceInput&skin=blueSky).
But instead of just show the text, which gonna be `check-in` when clicked would show a calendar from jquery [datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#default).

Something like this:

[image]

How can I show this calendar with the `placeholder` showing too ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primefaces has its own date picker.

```
<p:calendar id="date_checkin"> 
    <p:watermark for="date_checkin" value="Check-in" />  
</p:calendar>

<p:calendar id="date_checkout"> 
    <p:watermark for="date_checkout" value="Check-out" />  
</p:calendar>
```